# R devtools not available for R 3.0.1?

Tags: windows, r, devtools

After installing Rtools30, the installation of devtools fails on a Windows 7 32 bit system:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/hharmsen/Downloads/devtools_1.2.zip", repos = NULL)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘C:/Users/hharmsen/Downloads/devtools_1.2.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

When installing directly, devtools seems to install correctly, but upon loading there is an error:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
WARNING: Rtools 3.0 found on the path at c:/Rtools is not compatible with R 3.0.1.

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, remove the incompatible version from your PATH, then run find_rtools().
```

However installing devtools on R 3.0.gave no problems on a Debian 64 bit system.
Also Rtools should be compatible [R >2.15.1 to R 3.0.x].
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: See also the discussion at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/pull/298 It is a known problem which has been fixed in the development version but which has not made it into a release version. You will have to install the development version to make the message go away, but you can also just ignore it since you know it to be compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gave an **absolute path and file** to `install.packages()`, maybe the file is not at that location?

As explained the [relevant webpage](http://www.rstudio.com/projects/devtools/) your first try should probably be

```
 install.packages("devtools")
```

as this is a CRAN package.

Comment: That is a *Warning* which is not an *Error*. Are you by chance confusing the two?  The package appears to load just fine...

Comment: Rtools30.exe is what i downloaded, there is nothing more recent. it claims to be compatible: "R >2.15.1 to R 3.0.x".

Comment: Please re-read what I just wrote.  If it really annoys you, use `devtools` to reinstall the `devtools` sources, after commenting out the warning.

Comment: You are right, it was a warning not an error. Just loaded the library and everything works [and no more warning]. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Always a pleasure.  The convention here is "accept" and/or "upvote" a suitable answer.  Only you as the person asking can "accept" (click on  tickmark); anybody can up- or downvote.  That's how the system works here.